# ContactShare - RowCause not writable only in Test context

Tags: apex-managed-sharing

I have encountered a very strange behaviour where this field **ContactShare.RowCause** seems to be **NOT** writable only in test context. In the normal non-test context, this field is getting updated.
Note that this behaviour is peculiar only to ContactShare object, i tried Apex managed sharing on another custom object(Payment__c) and there was no problem updating the field RowCause on the Payment__sharing object.

Can anyone throw light on this?

Comment: Check the Running User ?Can you paste your test class here ?That should help debug .Looks like your running User in Test class has no permission

Comment: I am not running it as any specific user, if not, it runs as a SystemAdmin? Even if it was a permission issue,  why should only that field have the limitation?

Comment: If you don't use `runAs`, the test runs as the user who executed it. If they can't see the field, it would come back `null`.